# Difference between median and mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Is there any test if there is a significant difference between median and mean? Can those values be used to measure the skewness? Or does such a measurement make any sense at all?

Comment: ¿Are you asking if there is a statistical test to assess for the significance between the values? Or ¿are you just interested in knowing if there is any type of test—like a graphical measure?

Answer (score 2):

There is an article in the Journal of Statistical Education on this topic.

It is at

> Doane, David P. and Seward, Lori E.; Measuring Skewness: A Forgotten Statistic?; Journal of Statistics Education; Volume 19, Number 2(2011)

It contains both a good discussion of the principal statistics, but includes a Monte Carlo based test on them.

For a variety of reasons, it is a very useful statistic.  Imagine, for example, you were drawing data from a known normal distribution, but the data was significantly skewed.  That would be an indicator that the sample was an extreme subset of the set of possible subsets of the normal.